# Why is the transparency on my particles not working once exported to Godot?

Tags: node-editor, particles, export, transparency

I am new to blender. I am using blender 2.8 version. Recently I created a grass setup with the help of a tutorial video. In which I applied transparency for outside of grass using node editor. It renders completely fine. But if I export it to Godot, the meshes and materials exported perfectly. But the transparency from node editor is not applied. So instead of seeing a grass, all I see is a plane with grass image. I added the screenshots for your reference.

[image]

[image: Godot screenshot]

Comment: This is more of a Godot question than a Blender question, so this question is likely to be closed for being off topic. Before that happens, though, have you enabled "Use Alpha Scissor" and played with the slider under the parameters tab of your material in Godot?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found Godot uses the alpha value of the albedo color as transparency.

A blender material with transparency enabled and the alpha value changed looks right in Blender, but doesn't work in Godot:

[image: Blender's transparency doesn't work in Godot]

As you see, it correctly turned on the "Transparent" flag, but still has no alpha.

You have to change the alpha value of the albedo color in the Blender material for it to work:

[image: Changed alpha in the albedo color exports correctly to Godot]